# Can't access hats

Tags: support

This morning I noticed on my user profile summary page that I had some hats.  I clicked on the little number and snowflake icon.  It popped up a small message *Your Hats loading* over some other text, then nothing:

[image]

The browser says *Error on page* in the status bar at the bottom.  I just checked, and I am using IE8, which is the highest version that runs on the WinXP box I am on right now.

Comment: I know a lot of good reasons to keep running XP (still use it myself for an Agilent DSO and some device programmers under a virtual machine) but a lot of 3rd party browsers like Firefox / Chrome work under XP and IMO are generally better than IE. In about 4 months XP patch support ends so exploits won't be fixed, so you probably want to plan an upgrade for general Internet access.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, Internet Explorer is the 555 of the Internet browsers...

Comment: I can understand users who wanted to stay with XP when Vista came out, but sooner or later you'll have to upgrade, and then I suggest Windows 7. It's as robust as XP, and you can easily get the XP look and feel back, with software like "Classic Start Menu".

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, but IE8 is not a browser we support anymore. For now we try to still keep the major site functionality workin in it, but Winter Bash isn't part of that.

Comment: I can understand you wanting to not support old stuff, but this seems a bit extreme.  It worked last year with a even older browser.  Why is such new HTML needed that old browsers can't handle it?  It seems a lot of web sites, now this one included apparently, use phancy HTML just to use phancy HTML, whether there is really a need for it or not.  Also, IE8 is the latest IE supported on WinXP, which is what that machine happens to be running.  It's unreasonably to expect people to upgrade to new versions of OS, browsers, and other things when the old stuff is working fine.

Comment: The HTML part is usually the smallest problem when supporting older browsers; CSS and JavaScript are usually where the issues are at. And your accusations are a bit unfounded. It's not about "phancy" HTML just for the sake of it. You can make anything work in IE8 as well, but testing and fixing things in an ancient browser like that just takes a disproportionate amount of time and work. And your last sentence depends on the definition of "working fine" -- with XP no longer getting updates coming next year, you're sitting on a ticking time bomb by accessing the internet with it.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are enough modern browsers that run even on Windows XP; even there, it's not like you have to run Internet Explorer.